# Expectation of Dirac function

Tags: statistical-significance, covariance, expected-value, dirac-delta

I am having some trouble understanding how to derive the expectation of white noise.
Assuming we have $W(x)$ which is a continuous white noise process with zero mean and unit variance, Thus
$$cov\big(W(x),W(x^{'})\big)=\delta_{xx^{'}}$$

Where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta function defined as 
$$+\infty \ ,x=x^{'}  $$
$$0\ , x\neq x^{'}$$
Also, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x).dx=1$$

Baed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise), the Dirac delta function here was invented to replace the Kronecker delta function to be able to define white noise, expectation and covariance in continuous time.

How is this derived ? I understand that to integrate white noise we introduce this dirac delta function, but how is the covariance derived ?

Comment: That looks like a "bastardized" cross of the Kronecker and Dirac deltas. Perhaps this should be more like $\mathrm{Cov}[W(x),W(y)]=\delta(x-y)$ ?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have updated my question , however, why is $E\big(W(x),W(x^{'})\big)=0$ when $t_{1}\neq t_{2}$ on what mathmatical bases is this derived, what are the assumptions ?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 yes I belive what you said is true that $$E\big(W(x),W(x^{'})\big)=\delta(x-x^{'})$$, but how do you reach such equation ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a dirac indicator function, not a delta function. In other words $\delta_{xx'}=1$ iff $x=x'$ and 0 otherwise. In this case when $x=x'$ then you're just measuring the variance of white noise, which is 1. It's 0 otherwise since white noise is independent in time.

Comment: What you are mentioning is the Kronecker delta function (Usually reffered to as indicator function). The Dirac delta function is its continuous counterpart, however it is defined differently

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be *derived* here. (Continuous-time) white noise 
(at least for
engineers if not for mathematicians and statisticians (cf. *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134193/15941)* on math.SE)) is *defined* to be a wide-sense stationary zero-mean random process with autocorrelation function $K\delta(t)$ where $K$ is a positive constant and $\delta(t)$
denotes the Dirac delta or impulse. The Dirac delta is not a *function* 
in the
usual sense of the term, and in particular, $\delta(0)$ is not the
numerical value of the "function" at $0$. Thus, the OP's statement that 
$\delta(t)$ equals "infinity" when $t = 0$, and $0$ when $t\neq 0$ is incorrect. But, while the Dirac delta is not a function, it *does*
behave as a function in *integrals* when one is doing things like
change of variables etc.

The reasons why white noise with autocorrelation function a Dirac delta
is so useful to engineers are described in 
Appendix A of *[this Lecture Note of mine](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf).* In it I say (among many other polemical assertions)

> White noise
>   is a fictitious zero-mean WSS random process that is 
>   assumed to 
>   exist in the input of a linear time-invariant system 
>   (impulse response $h(t)$ and transfer function 
>   $H(f)$) whenever the system output includes a 
>   zero-mean WSS random process with power
>   spectral density proportional to $\vert H(f)\vert^2$.
>   The constant of proportionality is written as $\frac{N_0}{2}$
>   and is called *the two-sided power spectral density*
>   of the white noise process since $\frac{N_0}{2}$ is the value
>   of the power spectral density of the white noise process
>   for all frequencies $f$, $-\infty < f < \infty$.
>   The autocorrelation function of the white noise process is 
>   $\frac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau)$ where $\delta(\tau)$ denotes
>   the unit impulse. 
>   }}
>
> Why does all this work?  Well, in many cases, the noise
>   present at the filter input has power spectral density 
>   that can be approximated as
>   $S_X(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}\operatorname{rect}(f/2f_0)$ where $f_0$ is on the order
>   of $10^{13}$ Hz or so.  Now, for all 
>   practically implementable filters,
>   $\vert H(f)\vert^2$ is *very small* for 
>   large $\vert f \vert$, and thus there is a negligibly
>   small difference between the ``exact'' value
>   $ \frac{N_0}{2}\int_{-f_0}^{+f_0}\vert H(f)\vert^2\,df$
>   of the noise variance at the filter output and the
>   approximate value 
>   $ \frac{N_0}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert H(f)\vert^2\,df$
>   given by the white noise assumption.
>   On the other hand, the mathematical manipulations
>   are a lot easier with the white noise assumption, 
>   e.g. integrals whose integrands include impulses
>   are easy to evaluate.  Thus, 
>   with the caveat that we never try to observe white noise
>   physically, we never look very closely at the random variables
>   in the white noise process, and we never try to tap the infinite power 
>   of a white noise process to solve the world's energy
>   problems, this fictitious random process can help simplifying the
>   analysis of many problems in digital communication systems.